# Filling form fields from JSON Array with JQuery clone

Tags: jquery, json

I have implemented JQuery Clone as in the following link :

http://jsfiddle.net/sunalive/gqQnJ/13/

The same transaction is used for posting and displaying values. I need to display the values from a JSON array (built using PHP from DB) which has values for multiple rows.  The JSON Array sample is as below:

```
 [{"lineNo":"000001","txtLink":"sddf","txtSelect":"2","txtCheck":"X"},
  {"lineNo":"000002","txtLink":"sdfd","txtSelect":"4","txtCheck":""},
  {"lineNo":"000003","txtLink":"frf","txtSelect":"5","txtCheck":"X"}]
```

While displaying the same, the row has to clone (as to the number of rows) and values to be shown in the appropriate fields.  I will not know the name of the fields or what is coming in the JSON array as everything is generated dynamically at runtime.  However, the field names will be of the notation *item['fieldname'][]* in my form (in the cloned line) where *fieldname = key* in the JSON array.

I was able to successfully clone rows as below where itemarr holds the JSON array.

```
  $(itemarr).each(function(index){ 
     $('.gridcontainer').append(emptyItems.clone());

  }
```

But I have no clue how to display the values into the form fields with dynamic clone.

Can anyone help me achieve this?  Thanks for your time and help.

**Update:** I had found my solution (Thanks Andreas!) and the same is available in the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id="grid">
    <tr id="emptyItems" style="display:none">
        <td><input type="text" name="item['a'][]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item['b'][]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item['c'][]" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

.

```
var rows = [
    { "a": 1.1, "b": 1.2, "c": 1.3 },
    { "a": 2.1, "b": 2.2, "c": 2.3 },
    { "a": 3.1, "b": 3.2, "c": 3.3 }
];

$(function() {
    $.each(rows, function(i, row) {
        var newRow = $("#emptyItems").clone().show().appendTo("#grid"),
            inputs = newRow.find("input");

        inputs.each(function() {
            var name = /item\['([^'])'\].*/.exec(this.name)[1];
            this.value = row[name] || "";
        });
    });
});
```

​
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VXRrp/)

Comment: Thank you Andreas.  I'll try this today.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I tried your solution today. It seemed to work in isolation however, when I put this in my implementation, it didn't work as expected. My implementation can be found in this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/16/). Are you able to see where am going wrong? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: 1. The item names are different than the ones supplied with the question 2. you have to `.clone()` the first row for each item in the array not just once before the first `.each()` 3. your edited version of the regular expression doesn't fit the "new" item names 4. the html markup isn't valid 5. `.live()` is deprecated as of version 1.7 - edited and working (and stripped) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/17/)

Comment: Hi Andreas, I cannot strip off those codes because I'm using the same transaction for both create and display.  However, as suggested by you, I removed the `.live()` and rewrote all with `.on()` to make it compatible with JQ1.7+.  I have rewritten the code which came very close to what I wanted (still not quite there, as it posts only the last row data twice instead of all rows).  The code is at [http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/23/](http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/23/).  Can you please look into and suggest corrections?  Thanks for your help and patience, I realize am troubling you too much.

Comment: You're ignoring my comments, you're editing my working example till it isn't working and you're then asking me to fix it one more time...? I've just made 2 changes to your code and its working fine. At first I removed the wrong placed `.clone()` which I've already written in my last comment (2.) and then I've copied my working example from the same comment into your example... -> works ;) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/24/)

Comment: Thankyou very much Andreas.  Your guidance helped me achieve what I wanted. Though your solution looked cleaner, I could not implement it as it didn't work with other functions and that misplaced clone was very much required for keeping the other functions intact. Still I managed to work my way out with the valuable tip you gave about that clone.  My code is placed at [http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/27/](http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/27/).  Thank you very much for your kindness to help me.